# ValueError with recursive function in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def recursive(start, end, datelist):

    results = ga.GAnalytics().create_query(profile_id, 
                             metrics, 
                             start,
                             end,
                             dimensions).execute()

    if results.get("containsSampledData") is True:

        x = len(datelist) / 2

        recursive(datelist[0],datelist[:x][-1],datelist[:x])
        recursive(datelist[x:][0],datelist[-1],datelist[x:])

    else:

        unsampled_date_ranges = []

        for x, y in start, end:
            unsampled_date_ranges.append((x, y))


recursive(start_date, end_date, date_list)
```

The function above takes a start date, end date and an inclusive list of dates based on the start and end dates.   If first checks if the data returned for the initial date range is sampled, if it is then the date range is split in half then checked, and so on.

My issue is with the else statement.  To make sure the function worked I tried `print start +  " - " + end` which returned the expected date ranges.  Ideally, I would like the data to be returned as a list of tuples, so I tried the above, but unfortunately I am getting this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack` here `for x, y in start, end:`

What is the issue with my code in my `else` statement and how can I get it to return a list of tuples?

Comment: Are `start` and `end` lists?

Comment: They are just strings.

Comment: So what do you expect the `for x, y in start, end:` loop to *do* then? There isn't anything much to loop over there.

Comment: I thought that any time the something goes through the else statement it could be appended to the `unsampled_date_ranges` list.  I guess I don't need the loop right?

Comment: Indeed, you don't need a loop there; for each recursive call you only have the one `start` and `end` values. You need to think about how you'll return the list back to the caller (which could be a recursive function call).

Comment: Would making a global variable and appending to a list outside the function work?

Comment: Sure, appending to a global works.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but is that not considered best practice?  I feel like read somewhere that using global variables is not ideal.

Comment: No, it is indeed not best practice. :-) What is your goal here though; to recursively find all start and end dates not covered?

Comment: The goal is to find the largest date ranges that return unsampled data.  My friend referred to what we are doing as a shitty version of quick sort, if that means anything. I guess the end goal is to have a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a start and end date given by the recursive function.

Comment: Then I guess you need to return `[(start, end)]` from the `else` branch, and in the `if` branch concatenate the return values of the recursive calls and return that concatenated list. Is there any recursive call that'll return an empty list instead?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your last question means...pretty new to all of this.

Comment: The problem for me is that I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You also don't appear to handle the case where `datelist` is empty (which is an inevitability as you are passing in smaller and smaller subsets of the list). Those are end-conditions; what should be happening when `datelist` is empty, what should be returned from a recursive call in all other conditions.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I will work on this a little more and edit this post or create a new one if I get stuck again.  Thanks for all of your help.